# Primes in a certain arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Primes $=_m 1 $. For any positive integer m, prove that arithmetic progression

$$1 +m, 1 + 2m, 1 + 3m, ... $$

contains infinitely many primes.

How can we prove that it suffices to show that for all $m$ positive, the arithmetic progression contains at least one prime?

Comment: Hint: anything of the form $1 + i(jm)$ is in the progression.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, sorry, lost me with your hint. Perhaps I'm just being dense today...

Comment: Suppose the a.p. $1+2m, 1+4m, 1+6m, \ldots$ contains a prime,
and the a.p. $1+3m, 1+6m, 1+9m, \ldots$ contains a prime,
and the a.p. $1+4m, 1+8m, 1+12m, \ldots$ contains a prime, etc.  The set of those primes is unbounded, and thus consists of infinitely many primes, which are all in the a.p. $1+m, 1+2m, 1+3m, \ldots$.

Comment: Of course the hard part of the proof is to show that the a.p. contains at least one prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @RobertIsrael in the comments.

Given that for all positive integers $n$ there is a prime in the arithmetic progression
$$
S_n=\{1+n,1+2n,1+3n,\ldots\}
$$

then $S_m$ must contain at least one prime. But it cannot contain a largest prime, since for any $N$ the subsequence $S_{Nm}\subseteq S_m$ must contain a prime larger than $N$, thus it must contain infinitely many.